# Redis inter-container communication fails after restart of swarm manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have the following setup on my 1 manager - 1 worker swarm installation.

```
ID                     HOSTNAME   STATUS  AVAILABILITY MANAGER
az8ptk865hkvbbva99gjv  web1-dev   Ready   Active       Leader
cohv346j0f4p3s8t9xnpi  web2-dev   Ready   Active              


version: '3'
services:
  master:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - redis
          - redis-master
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

  slave:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --slaveof redis-master 6379 --slave-read-only no
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - redis
          - redis-slave
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
```

After starting the service with
`docker stack deploy -c redis.yml redis`, I get working Redis master-slave setup, I can ping master container in slave and opposite.

If I restart the manager node, Redis slave, that is running in worker, loses the connection to Redis master in swarm manager node, and I can't ping the master node from slave.

The only thing that makes my setup work again is to restart docker service in worker node.

Are there any other way to make inter-container communication work after manager node restart without the need to touch worker nodes?

Comment: If you do a `docker exec` to get a shell inside one of the containers, are you able to resolve the dns and actually make the necessary tcp connection? Sometimes, icmp echo requests are useful for diagnosis white but they don't always tell us everything we need to know.

Comment: On slave, when cluster is operational:
ping redis-master
PING redis-master (10.0.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.114 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms


On slave after restarting swarm manager:
ping redis-master
ping: bad address 'redis-master'